# Error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ifstream'

Tags: c++, winforms

I am developing a C++ Windows Form app, that when user click the button, it reads clickcount number from a txt file, then does some features and writes the new clickcount number back to the txt file.

When there was only ofstream code, it run well. But after i've added ifstream code, this error appeared:

> Error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ifstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I've already included `<fstream>` and `<iostream>`.

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    //Some visible and invisible code for label

    std::ifstream file1;
    file1.open("Progress.txt");
    file1 >> clickcount;
    file1.close();

    clickcount = ++clickcount;

    ...

    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("Progress.txt");
    file << clickcount;
    file.close();
```

Comment: i'm sorry. I've edited it

Comment: What is `clickcount` declared as?

Comment: public ref class NNYT : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{  unsigned short int clickcount = 0 ...

Answer (score -1):

I've solved my problem

Declare clickcount like this:

```
#pragma endregion
   private: System::Void button1_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
       int clickcount;
       ...}
```

Not in `public ref class`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with declaring it as a member of your Form class. Making it a local variable of the click event handler won't be able to track the count across multiple clicks anymore. Not to mention one event handler can't access local variables of another event handler (your "solution" makes it local to button1, but your question is about using it in button2)